# Python Pandas - Compare 2 dataframes, multiple parameters

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have two tables.  One (df below) has approximately 18,000 rows, and the other (mapfile below) has ~800,000 rows.  I need a solution that can work with such large DataFrames.

Here is a toy example:
Table 1 - df

```
Sample    Chr    Start     End    Value
S1        1       100      200     1
S1        2       200      250     1
S2        1       50        75     5
S2        2       150      225     4
```

Table 2 - mapfile

```
Name    Chr    Position
P1       1      105
P2       1      60
P3       1      500
P4       2      25
P5       2      220
P6       2      240
```

I'm trying to do something like the following (my syntax is wrong, but I think the idea comes across):

```
for mapline in mapfile:
    for dfline in df:
       if df[dfline]['Chr'] == mapfile[mapline]['Chr']
           if mapfile[mapline]['Position'] > df[dfline]['Start'] & mapfile[mapline]['Position'] < df[dfline]['End']
                  newdf[['Name','Chr','Position','Value', 'Sample']] = pd.DataFrame([ mapfile[mapline]['Name'], mapfile[mapline]['Chr'], mapfile[mapline]['Position'], df[dfline]['Value'], df[dfline]['Sample'] ] )
```

In words:
I need to go through each item (line) in mapfile and see if its position is between any of the START & ENDs on each CHR in the df. If it is, I need to add it to a new file with the Name, Chr, Position, Sample, and Value fields from the two tables.

Output table of toy data:

```
Name    Chr    Position    Value   Sample
P1       1      105         1       S1
P2       1      60          5       S2
P5       2      220         1       S1
P5       2      220         4       S2
P6       2      240         1       S1
```

So far:
I've got what I have above, and have been having issues figuring out the syntax to just do a general loop in python.  However, my understanding is that this may be much easier with a package such as pandas or NumPy?  Please help me find the most efficient way to do this, and some help with the syntax along the way would be great.

A few related posts that I tried but couldn't make work
[What is the most efficient way to loop through dataframes with pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837722/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-loop-through-dataframes-with-pandas)
[How to iterate over rows in a DataFrame in Pandas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16476924/how-to-iterate-over-rows-in-a-dataframe)
[Append column to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602947/append-column-to-pandas-dataframe)
[Conditionally fill column values based on another columns value in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10715519/conditionally-fill-column-values-based-on-another-columns-value-in-pandas)

Comment: Could you add code to generate the toy example? Also, could you list out the final output for that example?

Comment: @Divakar , I don't know how make code to generate the example in python.  Sorry.  But I WILL add the final output as soon as I get to a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC you can use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) and [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp1=u"""Sample;Chr;Start;End;Value
S1;1;100;200;1
S1;2;200;250;1
S2;1;50;75;5
S2;2;150;225;4"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp1) to filename
dfline = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp1), sep=";")

temp2=u"""Name;Chr;Position
P1;1;105
P2;1;60
P3;1;500
P4;2;25
P5;2;220
P6;2;240"""
#after testing replace io.StringIO(temp2) to filename
mapfile = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp2), sep=";")
```

```
print dfline
  Sample  Chr  Start  End  Value
0     S1    1    100  200      1
1     S1    2    200  250      1
2     S2    1     50   75      5
3     S2    2    150  225      4
print mapfile
  Name  Chr  Position
0   P1    1       105
1   P2    1        60
2   P3    1       500
3   P4    2        25
4   P5    2       220
5   P6    2       240

#merge by column Chr
df = pd.merge(dfline, mapfile, on=['Chr'])

#select by conditions
df = df[(df.Position > df.Start) & (df.Position < df.End)]

#subset of df
df =  df[['Name','Chr','Position','Value', 'Sample']]
```

```
print df
   Name  Chr  Position  Value Sample
0    P1    1       105      1     S1
4    P2    1        60      5     S2
7    P5    2       220      1     S1
8    P6    2       240      1     S1
10   P5    2       220      4     S2

#if you need reset index
print df.reset_index(drop=True)
  Name  Chr  Position  Value Sample
0   P1    1       105      1     S1
1   P2    1        60      5     S2
2   P5    2       220      1     S1
3   P6    2       240      1     S1
4   P5    2       220      4     S2
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me (I'm using the merge function); the output has 0 lines.  Do datatypes have to be the same?  I'm concerned mine aren't.  I imported the files using the pandas.read_csv function.

Comment: Your dataframes `dfline` and `mapfile` are indexes like me? Try `print dfline.index` and output is `Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 3], dtype='int64')`

Comment: Yes.  Output is Int64Index()

Comment: @GaiusAugustus I guess the columns targeted by `merge` must have the same type. You can do something like `df1.Chr = df1.Chr.astype(int)` and the same on your other DataFrame if they aren't already the same.

Comment: @GaiusAugustus you can check dtypes by `print dfline.dtypes, mapfile.dtypes` and then use comment by `mgc` if are different in column `Chr`. @mgc thanks.

Comment: Okay, I've got this now, but it has one major issue: First, you merge everything together, then check for the condition.  My files are very large (one has 18,000 rows and the other has 800,000 rows).  That means it takes a long time to run, and/or I have to split the files and run them piecemeal and then cat them together.  I didn't specify this in the original post; I will go back and add it.