# Create a dataframe using for loop results in Python

Tags: python, for-loop, dataframe

When I run the for loop below

```
for i in df:
    d = df[pd.notnull(df[i])]
    c = df[df[i]>str(1)].count()
    print(c)
```

I get a results below

```
1     244
2     122
3      53
4      75
dtype: int64
1     122
2     206
3      62
4      77
dtype: int64
```

I want to create a data frame which looks like below

```
   1   2
1 244 122
2 122 206
3  53  62
4  75  77
```

Can someone help me code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append column to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602947/append-column-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1):

Having an excerpt of your initial data would be useful, but from what I can gather you're only trying to append the two arrays together to obtain a pandas dataframe. That can be easily done with something like:

```
data = pd.DataFrame()

for i in df:
    d = df[pd.notnull(df[i])]
    c = df[df[i]>str(1)].count()
    data = data.join(c)

print(data)
```