# How can I align test data to predicted data with keras.prediction?

Tags: python, pandas, keras

I have a trained model and I am running prediction with `keras` via:

```
model = pets.get_model(input_size=input_units)
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.load_weights('models/2019-03-01-02-03-53.h5')

prediction = model.predict(X)
```

This gives me a list that looks like `[0.323 0.43 .099]` and so on. How can I map that to rows in my `X` (which is a `pandas` `DataFrame`) so that I have an easy representation of input to outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, `model.predict(X)` and `X` itself will already be in the same order (first value of `prediction` corresponds to `X`'s first row and so on).

For ease of visualization, you could try something like `X['predicitons'] = prediction` but that would add a column to `X`.

Comment: Oh snap - so simple! And it'll be perfectly aligned?

Comment: Yes. I updated the answer to add a little bit of context.

Comment: Wait - slight issue. My prediction has 3 columns. So I need to somehow add 3 columns?

Comment: Does your dataset have 3 different classes? If that's the case, then you can turn `prediction` into a DataFrame and join with X. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602947/append-column-to-pandas-dataframe