# Create an empty DataFrame an append a list to it in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to generate an Empty Dataframe and then adding a list as a new column with header to this DataFrame, I have such a code:

```
#define an empty dataframe
df()

start=0
for row in list1:
  blist=list()
  for data in list2:
    blist.append(data.Ordertype[0:row._c1]) 

  start=start + row._c1   
  #I would like to append blist now to  dataframe df() in this line
```

How can I do that? Do you have any Idea?

Comment: This is not how spark DataFrames are designed. Can you provide a [mcve] that explains in much more detail what your desired output is? There's likely a better way as this seems like an [XY problem](http://www.xyproblem.info).

Comment: I got my answer :)

Comment: If the accepted answer solves your problem, then this has nothing to do with pyspark or databricks. I'm removing those tags.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append column to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602947/append-column-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame()

start=0
for row in list1:
  blist=list()
  for data in list2:
    blist.append(data.Ordertype[0:row._c1]) 

  start=start + row._c1  
   df['col_name_iteration'] = pd.Series(blist)
```