# Combining dataframes without knowing the amount of columns

Tags: python, dataframe

I have Dataframe1, which is:

```
A          B
apple      tree
bed        house
triangle   cheese
```

And Dataframe 2:

```
C      D
dog    rabbit
cat    cheese
fish   gold
```

Is there a way to join them together like the below, without knowing what the columns in Dataframe 2 are, or how many of them there are?

```
A          B         C       D       
apple      tree      dog     rabbit
bed        house     cat     cheese
triangle   cheese    fish    gold
```

Comment: Have you done any research?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Append column to pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20602947/append-column-to-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if they both have the same number of rows you can do

`df = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)`

```
A          B         C       D       
apple      tree      dog     rabbit
bed        house     cat     cheese
triangle   cheese    fish    gold
```