# Append List values to DataFrame Column data

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I have a CSV file as below:

- **name**
- john
- eve

And a list: 
state=['India','US']

I want to add new column to the existing csv file with the list items as data to that column

What I want:

- **name**  -  **state**
- john      -   India
- eve       -    Us

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20602947/7370153) might interest you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by declaring a new list as a column.

code example:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'name': ['john', 'eve']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

state = ['India','US']
df['state'] = state

print(df)
```