# Joining multiple pandas dataframes as list, forces column types to float, but not if done sequentially

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I want to join several specific feature DataFrames (`X1`,`X2`) to main DataFrame `DATA`. DataFrames has same row counts, they are joined on the index.
This works as expected:

```
DATA = DATA.join(X1)
DATA = DATA.join(X2)
```

This approach casts all columns to float:

```
DATA = DATA.join([X1,X2])
```

Using concat also cast all columns to float:

```
DATA = pd.concat([DATA,X1,X2], axis = 1)
```

Based on [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46234582/4154250) I tried with dropping the index, but the result was the same:

```
DATA = pd.concat([DATA.reset_index(drop=True),X1.reset_index(drop=True),X2.reset_index(drop=True)], axis = 1)
```

Is there a way to use pandas `join` or `concat` method (not `merge`) and using a list of DataFrames as arguments, and return DataFrame with its column types intact?

Pandas 1.3.3 is used (on Kaggle).

Comment: Could you post some example data that reproduces the issue? I can't reproduce this based on your description. Casting the joined columns to float indicates that there are join keys present in `X1` and/or `X2`, but missing from `DATA`.

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler; Dataframes has nothing in common, except the index, which is the same in all three. And also the index is converted to float after the join.

Comment: Ah ok, got it. I'm still having trouble reproducing this on my own - I'm probably missing something obvious. Would you be able to edit into your question example DataFrames `X1` and `X2` (could copy-paste the output of `X1.to_dict()`) whose columns are cast to float when joined?

Comment: @PeterLeimbigler; In the meantime, I made several rearrangements to the notebook. As a consequence, I now cannot reproduce this as well. And this: DATA = DATA.join([X1, X2, X3, X_CD]) now works ...
I will try to search for the old notebook version and see if I can provide more helpful example.